# SwiftUI: View not updating when calling function with @Published property

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm encountering an issue in my SwiftUI app where a view isn't updating as expected when I call a function that modifies a property marked with @Published in my view model. Specifically, I have a DiscoverView that displays trending shows, and I'm trying to update the list of shows when certain filters are changed in DiscoverFiltersControls. However, the view doesn't reflect the updated list of shows.

DiscoverView

```
struct DiscoverView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: NavigationManager
    @StateObject var viewModel = DiscoverViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigation.discoverStack) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    DiscoverFiltersControls()

                    // Test: trending shows not updated after changing filters
                    ForEach(viewModel.trendingShows) { show in
                        Text(show.title)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.vertical)
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .navigationTitle("Discover")
            .toolbar { ProfileToolbar() }
            .environmentObject(DiscoverViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

DiscoverFiltersControls:

```
struct DiscoverFiltersControls: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: DiscoverViewModel

    var body: some View {
        let genreMenuName = viewModel.selectedGenre?.name ?? "Genre"
        let genreMenuVariant: ButtonVariant = viewModel.selectedGenre != nil
            ? .primary
            : .secondaryOutline

        HStack(spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(ShowType.allCases) { showType in
                let variant: ButtonVariant = viewModel.typeFilters.contains(showType)
                    ? .primary
                    : .secondaryOutline

                Button(showType.name) {
                    viewModel.typeFilters.toggle(showType)
                }
                .buttonStyle(StyledButton(variant, .small))
            }
            .onChange(of: viewModel.typeFilters) {
                viewModel.getTrendingShows()
            }

            Menu(genreMenuName, systemImage: "chevron.down") {
                ForEach(genresList) { genre in
                    if viewModel.selectedGenre == genre {
                        Button(genre.name, systemImage: "checkmark") {
                            viewModel.selectedGenre = nil
                        }
                    } else {
                        Button(genre.name) {
                            viewModel.selectedGenre = genre
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(StyledButton(genreMenuVariant, .small))
            .labelStyle(LabelLayout(.right, .small))

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

DiscoverViewModel:

```
@MainActor
final class DiscoverViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var typeFilters = ShowType.allCases
    @Published var selectedGenre: GenreInfo?
    @Published var trendingShows = [Show]()
    @Published var trendingPeople = [Person]()

    init() {
        self.getAll()
    }

    func getAll() {
        Task {
            await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
                group.addTask { await self.getTrendingShows() }
                group.addTask { await self.getTrendingPeople() }
            }
        }
    }

    func getTrendingShows() {
        Task {
            let isFiltered = !self.typeFilters.isEmpty && self.typeFilters.count != ShowType.allCases.count
            let endpoint: TrendingEndpoint = !isFiltered
                ? .all
                : self.typeFilters.contains(.movie) ? .movies : .tvSeries
            self.trendingShows = try await TMDbManager.shared.trending(endpoint).toShows()
        }
    }

    func getTrendingPeople() {
        Task {
            self.trendingPeople = try await TMDbManager.shared.trending(.people).toPeople()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Swift and I can't get around how to handle data in SwiftUI. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
@StateObject var viewModel = DiscoverViewModel()
```

Here you're creating a `DiscoverViewModel`, and holding it as a state object, which is correct.

```swift
.environmentObject(DiscoverViewModel())
```

Here you're creating a brand *new* `DiscoverViewModel` and injecting it into the environment, which is wrong. You want to pass in the single top-level object, so everything has the same reference:

```swift
.environmentObject(viewModel)
```

Comment: wow thank you! i feel so stupid haha

Answer (score -1):

The SwiftUI code isn't right, it should be like this:

```
struct DiscoverView: View {
    @State var selectedGenre: GenreInfo?
    let example: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ...
```

`body` will be called when the `@State var` or the `let` changes.

To use async/await in SwiftUI it is `.task` or `.task(id:)` not `Task`. From there you can call a async func that returns a result. If the func is defined in a struct that is not `@MainActor` (i.e. not a `View` struct) it will run on a background thread.

Comment: i'm confused. why would i define selectedGenre in my view, isn't it fine in the view model? and i didn't understand what you meant with the tasks, my view model is @MainActor and i've used Task {} directly instead of async because i need to call those functions in init() and onChange() which don't support concurrency

Comment: `View` struct is the view model. SwiftUI auto-generates the view objects for you based on your `View` struct view model hierarchy. it diffs the struct values, uses the difference to init, deinit, update, UIKit objects. Use `.task(id:)` for the async version of `onChange`.